# php login not working even if i enter the correct email and password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i am making an form system, the problem is, even if i entered the right username and password it still gave me password is wrong, i already tried to run the query on sql, and it works, the query is ok

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['pesan'])){
    if($_GET['pesan'] == "gagal"){
        echo "Login gagal! username dan password salah!";
    }else if($_GET['pesan'] == "logout"){
        echo "Anda telah berhasil logout";
    }else if($_GET['pesan'] == "belum_login"){
        echo "Anda harus login untuk mengakses halaman admin";
    }
}
?>


<form action="login.php" class="form-signin"> 
<center><h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2></center>      
    <img src="../media/Logo2.png" width="90%" height="90%">
    <br><br>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Masukkan username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Masukkan password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></td>
    </tr>    
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
</form>
```

here is the action file

```
<?php 
// mengaktifkan session php
session_start();

// menghubungkan dengan koneksi
include '../koneksi.php';

// menangkap data yang dikirim dari form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// menyeleksi data admin dengan username dan password yang sesuai
$data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM t_pelapor WHERE Email = '$username' AND pass = '$password'");

// menghitung jumlah data yang ditemukan
$cek = mysqli_num_rows($data);

if($cek > 0){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['status'] = "login";
    header("location:v_home.php");
}else{
    header("location:v_login.php?pesan=gagal");
}
?>
```

and this is my `t_pelapor` structure (the login table)

[my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vWVx.png)

Comment: Please stop asking questions with SQL injection vulnerable code. You've been asked before. Do some error checking on  the query. Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: check `mysqli_error($koneksi);` to see if it gives you an error message

Comment: no, it doesn't give me anything, it just blank white

Comment: you have to add koneksi.php code and file location

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an opening form tag at all in your html, here is that corrected. If your php file is in another place (I don't understand exactly from your question) you may need to add something like this `action="something.php"` to the form tag to call the specific php file.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['pesan'])){
    if($_GET['pesan'] == "gagal"){
        echo "Login gagal! username dan password salah!";
    }else if($_GET['pesan'] == "logout"){
        echo "Anda telah berhasil logout";
    }else if($_GET['pesan'] == "belum_login"){
        echo "Anda harus login untuk mengakses halaman admin";
    }
}
?>
<form id="whateveryouwant" name="whatever" method="POST">
<center><h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2></center>      
  <img src="../media/Logo2.png" width="90%" height="90%">
  <br><br>
  <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Masukkan username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Masukkan password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></td>
        </tr>    
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
</form>
```

As has been stated, this code is vulnerable to exploitation (SQL Injection) so I hope that this is an academic exercise, and not a production thing.

Comment: im sorry but, i already added the 'action='somethin.php' before, i will edit my question

Comment: @InFocus Missing `method="POST"` is probably the issue in your code.